# boto3 request_spot_instances method does not work with "UserData"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to make AWS EC2 spot instance request via AWS Lambda, and using boto3 to make call to EC2 API.

Now I can create spot instance, but "UserData" param is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import boto3
import json
import logging
import base64
import os
from pathlib import Path

def request_spot_instance(access_key, secret_key):
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2',
    aws_access_key_id = access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
    region_name = 'ap-northeast-1'
)
response = ec2_client.request_spot_instances(
    SpotPrice = '0.2',
    Type = 'one-time',
    LaunchSpecification = {
        'ImageId': 'ami-be4a24d9',
        'KeyName': 'my_key',
        'InstanceType':'c4.large',
        'UserData': base64.encodestring(u'#!/bin/sh \n touch foo.txt'.encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii'),
        'Placement':{},
        'SecurityGroupIds':[
            'sg-6bd2780c'
        ]
    }
)
return response


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = request_spot_instance(os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))
    print(response)
    return event, context

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lambda_handler("","")
```

I'm using this code with Python 2.7.11.

The response of request method is:

```
{u'SpotInstanceRequests': [{u'Status': {u'UpdateTime': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 23, 6, 11, 8, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'Code': 'pending-evaluation', u'Message': 'Your Spot request has been submitted for review, and is pending evaluation.'}, u'ProductDescription': 'Linux/UNIX', u'SpotInstanceRequestId': 'sir-cerib8cg', u'State': 'open', u'LaunchSpecification': {u'Placement': {u'AvailabilityZone': 'ap-northeast-1c'}, u'ImageId': 'ami-be4a24d9', u'KeyName': 'miz_private_key', u'SecurityGroups': [{u'GroupName': 'ssh only', u'GroupId': 'sg-6bd2780c'}], u'SubnetId': 'subnet-32c6626a', u'Monitoring': {u'Enabled': False}, u'InstanceType': 'c4.large'}, u'Type': 'one-time', u'CreateTime': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 23, 6, 11, 8, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'SpotPrice': '0.200000'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '285867eb-9303-4a6d-83fa-5ccfdadd482f', 'HTTPHeaders': {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 23 Dec 2016 06:11:08 GMT'}}}
```

This response does not not include "UserData", which seems differ from wrote in [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.request_spot_instances) manual.
I'm suspecting UserData param is not accepted.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Self resolved.

The user data shell script was executed at root "/" directory, and simply I could not find the generated file.

```
$ ls -al /foo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 23 07:03 /foo.txt
```